# What is a "meta component" in the context of bootstrap or as a general web design term?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web, terminology

In the documentation for the bootstrap [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default), navbar is described as a "meta component". As far as I can tell, this is the only component described as a "meta component", and I have not been able to find an explanation of this term.

What is a "meta component"? Is it just a throwaway term in the bootstrap documentation, or does it refer to a component with particular characteristics either within bootstrap or in web design in general?

Answer (score 1):

meta component is a component that consists some other components , for example bootstrap navbar consists navbar container , navbar header and navbar collapse.

In other words meta components is a collection of other components and have no special feature for themselves in most cases.
see the following link it may help.

https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-navbar

Answer (score 0):

I think needs some more clarification, as the term 'meta' is widely used in different contexts.

Generally meta can show up in 2 variations

*meta*- **adjective** : e.g. metaphysical | it means  it is part of the entity in a transitional way - here it means "beyond physical"

*meta*- **noun** : e.g. Metatheory | it means something is classified in a higher layer or in superordinate level - here it means "a theory that contains many other theories comprising the superordinate theory"

So blank94 was mostly right I think, as the association is that of an aggregation rather than a composition, meaning sub-parts are not bound to their meta-parts. A navbar can have elements that can comprise other elements of course. The 'special feature' of the meta-component is that it passes on it's very own unique styling rules.